# how to output file lists to text file using java

Tags: java

hello i am a newbie to java. i just started learning java last week.

below is a code I am using to display all files and the corresponding file sizes of a folder and it's subfolder.

However, instead of displaying the output in the Eclipse console, what I need to achieve is actually output the same data to a text file. I've been searching on the net on how to accomplish this over the last couple of days but I wasn't able to come to a solution.

Can someone advise me on what code to use to accomplish my task?

Thanks so much!

```
public class ReadFile1 {
public static void main(String[] a)throws IOException{
showDir(1, new File("/Users/User/Documents/1 eclipse test/testfolder1"));

//File file = new File("/Users/User/Documents/1 eclipse test/testfolder1/puppy4.txt");

//long fileSize = file.length();

}
static void showDir(int indent, File file) throws IOException {


 for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++)

      System.out.print('-');
System.out.println(file.getName() + " - " + file.length() / 1024 + " KB");


  if (file.isDirectory()) {
  File[] files = file.listFiles();
  for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    showDir(indent + 4, files[i]);  


   }

}

}
```

Comment: you could use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html

Comment: You can use java File IO operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your example converted :

```
public class ReadFile1
{
    public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException
    {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\test.txt",true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        showDir(out,1,new File("C:\\"));

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    static void showDir(BufferedWriter writer, int indent, File file) throws IOException
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < indent; i++)
        {
            writer.write('-');
            //System.out.print('-');
        }

        writer.write(file.getName() + " - " + file.length() / 1024 + " KB");
        writer.newLine();

        //System.out.println(file.getName() + " - " + file.length() / 1024 + " KB");

        if(file.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                showDir(writer,indent + 4, files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alexandre. i tried your code but got following errors...   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ReadFile1.showDir(ReadFile1.java:49)
 at ReadFile1.showDir(ReadFile1.java:51)
 at ReadFile1.main(ReadFile1.java:27)

Comment: @user2408281 have you changed paths with yours?

Comment: oh no i used your exact code... i thought it would be ok to use your code?

Comment: Well this is more an example :)

Comment: You are welcome, now you should mark as answered so other users won't think it is not!

Comment: Hey alexandre, could you let me know where's the best place to go to pick up java fast and learn to write the above code?

Comment: @user2408281 There is no best place, it depend on what kind of development you are doing. You can start with books, tutorials, etc. For SO, you should read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/about) :)

Comment: ok i've marked as answered by clicking on the checkmark. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your showDir with the file writing code as mentioned here:

```
File file = new File("info.txt");
 // if file doesnt exists, then create it
  if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
}

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
writer.println(file.getName() + " - " + file.length() / 1024 + " KB");
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will put the console output into the text file:

```
   try{
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
    System.setOut(out);
    }catch(SecurityException se){
       //Exception handling
      }
```

`setOut(PrintStream out)` reassigns the "standard" output stream.It throws `SecurityException` -- if a security manager exists and its checkPermission method doesn't allow reassigning of the standard output stream.